# How to get the value of what isin return

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using `.isin()` to check if all the values in `df1` are also in `df2`. I'm getting say `True 100` and `False 1`. How can I know which value is this `False` one?

Comment: just pass that mask to your df i.e `df[df.isin(....)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display results with:

```
import pandas as pd



data1 = {"id":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],'test':['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']}
data2={"id":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,100]}

df1=pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data2)

#df1['id'] value is in df2['id']
print("df1['id'] value is in df2['id']")
print(df1[df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])])

print("\n\n\n -------- \n\n\n")


#df1['id'] value isnot in df2['id']
print("df1['id'] value isnot in df2['id']")
print(df1[~df1['id'].isin(df2['id'])])
```

results:

```
df1['id'] value is in df2['id']
   id test
0   1    a
1   2    b
2   3    c
3   4    d
4   5    e
5   6    f
6   7    g
7   8    h
8   9    i



 --------



df1['id'] value isnot in df2['id']
     id test
9  10.0    j
```